# How to bold the label in selected row using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I am writing a code for Bootstrap panel, and I would like to make label bold for the selected row. Here is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="costCentersList" class="col-md-6 no-padding-right-left">
<div class="panel panel-default no-MP">
<div class="panel-heading">Cost Centers <span class="floatRight"><a href="#" id="newCostCenter" onClick="newCostCenter();">Create New Cost Center</a></span></div>
<div class="panel-body">
<ul>
<li >
<input type="radio" name="costCenter" value="Marketing" id="btnRadioCC1">
<label >Marketing</label> <span class="floatRight">
<input type="button" value="Assign Employees" class="btn btn-primary btnAssignCC btn-rounded-4">
</span></li>
<li>
<input type="radio" name="costCenter" value="Developer" id="btnRadioCC2">
<label>Developer</label><span class="floatRight">
<input type="button" value="Assign Employees" class="btn btn-primary btnAssignCC btn-rounded-4">
</span></li>
</ul>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$('#costCentersList li').on('click',function(){
$('#costCentersList li').removeClass('highlight-row');
$(this).addClass('highlight-row');
var abc = $(this).find('label');
$('abc').attr('style','font-weight:bold');
})
```

Comment: $(".classname").css('font-weight','bold');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that class `highlight-row` has property: `font-weight:bold`.

And replace the function content with:

```
$('#costCentersList li label').removeClass('highlight-row');
$(this).find('label').addClass('highlight-row');
```